# ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

My code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ". static::$table_name ." (";
$sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
$sql .= ") VALUES ('";
$sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
$sql .= "')";
```

output:

```
echo $sql;
//INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('', 'lukeduke', '123456', 'Luke', 'Duke')
```

When I run this query, I get:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

Comment: Did you read the error message ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO users (username, password, first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('lukeduke', '123456', 'Luke', 'Duke')` would do as long as your id is an auto increment.

Comment: An empty string is not an integer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use this insert, you must provide an integer value in your sql instead of an empty string, it should by like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, first_name, last_name)
VALUES (1, 'lukeduke', '123456', 'Luke', 'Duke')
```

or if your id is autoincremental you can have your sql like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('lukeduke', '123456', 'Luke', 'Duke')
```

In this case, this should be your code:

```
//extracting your first element of the array (id in this case)
$attributes = array_slice($attributes, 1);

$sql = "INSERT INTO ". static::$table_name ." (";
$sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
$sql .= ") VALUES ('";
$sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
$sql .= "')";
```

Read more at:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 5):

what is your `id` column type?

if it is integer and auto increment, pass `null` value to it

Comment: *what is your id column type?* Use comments for clarification; Don't do guess work in your answer

Comment: @Rizier123 So why not downvote? (Up to you of course, but helps to shift poor answers down, or gone..)