# Using JQuery AJAX and php to fetch data to a mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

Im trying to insert data into my database with AJAX but dont working. 
I can verify that im connected to the database but when i click it doesnt insert the data. thanks

with a click function i take the 2 parameter that i wanna insert in my database.

```
$( "#q_answer1" ).click(function () {
      var q_no = $("#q_no").val(); 
      var main_no = $("#total_no").val();

      $.ajax({
         url: "server.php",
         type: "post",
         async: false,
         data: {
            "done": 1,
            "username": q_no,
            "comment": main_no

         }, 
         success: function(){
            $("#q_no").val('');
            $("#total_no").val('');
         }
      });
  });
```

And here is the php file, first connect to the ddbb and insert the 2 values with the mysql_query.

```
<?php
include("dbh.php");
if (isset($_POST['done'])) {
   $q_no = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
   $total_no = mysql_escape_string($_POST['comment']);

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO variables(id, names) VALUES('{$q_no}', '{$total_no}')");
   exit();
}
?>
```

html is like this:

```
<div id="total_no">1</div>
<div id="q_answer1" class="btn left_b">yes</div>
```

Comment: and please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: `mysql_query` will be removed from PHP.

Comment: PDO tutorial http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use PDO, to connect to the database instead of the old driver, which PHP no longer supports. with PDO you can use prepared statements to prevent [sql injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

[PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Preparing_Statements_using_SQL_functions)

[filter_var() Constants](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filter.asp)

**dbh.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = 'db';

try {

  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    exit($e->getMessage());
  }

?>
```

**serve.php**

```
<?php

include("dbh.php");
if (isset($_POST['done'])) {

   $q_no = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $total_no = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

try {

  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO variables(id, names) VALUES(?, ?)");
  $stmt->execute(array($q_no, $total_no));

  echo json_encode(["message" => "success"]); // sends success response to front-end 

} catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo json_encode(["message" => $e->getMessage() ]); // sends error response to front-end
}


}
 ?>
```

in your ajax check if the data was inserted or not.

```
$("#q_answer1").click(function() {
  var q_no = $("#q_no").val();
  var main_no = $("#total_no").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type: "post",
    async: false,
    data: {
      "done": 1,
      "username": q_no,
      "comment": main_no

    },
    success: function(data) {

      const respose = JSON.parse(data);

      if (respose.message === 'success') { // data was inserted 

        $("#q_no").val('');
        $("#total_no").val('');

      }else {
        alert(respose.message); // some error has occured
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @junius-ln  i got this error after implementing your code:  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

Comment: @Jacofki it means you tried to insert a string into integer column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462919/error-1366-hy000-incorrect-integer-value-for-column-id-at-row-1

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error in jquery

```
$qAnswer1.click(function () {
```

Should be

```
$('#q_answer1').click(function () {
```

You can try following to test

```
$( "#q_answer1" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Include the jquery at the top of your page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Full working code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="total_no">1</div>
<div id="q_answer1" class="btn left_b">yes</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "#q_answer1" ).click(function () {
    var q_no = $("#q_no").val(); 
    var main_no = $("#total_no").val();

  $.ajax({
     url: "ajax.php",
     type: "post",
     async: false,
     data: {
        "done": 1,
        "username": q_no,
        "comment": main_no

     }, 
     success: function(){
        $("#q_no").val('');
        $("#total_no").val('');
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

in your PHP file try to print `$_POST` to see its working.

Comment: @Jacofki have you included jquery at the top ?

Comment: @its working, if you click on yes , try the handler code

Comment: Thanks @rakesh-jakhar, after that change i get a  500 (Internal Server Error) in the server.php (for you ajax.php).

Comment: make sure the path of server.php

Comment: is correct, and also i get this message:                                            
 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take value of div as mentioned below,

```
var q_no = $("#q_no").text(); 
var main_no = $("#total_no").text();
```

Pass data in key-value Pair, After pass first key-value data concate other data with & sign key.

```
$( "#q_answer1" ).click(function () {
          var q_no = $("#q_no").val(); 
          var main_no = $("#total_no").val();

          $.ajax({
             url: "server.php",
             type: "post",
             async: false,
             data: 'done=' + 1 + '&username=' + q_no + '&comment=' + main_no,
             success: function(){
                $("#q_no").val('');
                $("#total_no").val('');
             }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `val()` on `div`. Try using `text()` and then check if your `server.php` is getting these value.

Thanks